# Debugging ASP.NET MVC3 application hosted on Local IIS Webserver

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, azure

I've managed to use the local IIS Webserver to host my MVC3 application, and I can debug it and everything, *from the machine that is hosting it.* - however, when I send a request from another machine (my Mac, which is running my Windows in a Parallels VM), I get the expected result, but the **debugger wont stop at my breakpoints!**

I tried adding a `Debugger.Break();` to my action, and that crashes the w3wp.exe ..

To, so summarize: **Local requests are working, and can be debugged. External requests are working, but they cannot be debugged.**

In my project's properties, I set the `Use Local IIS Webserver`, `Use IIS Express` is **unchecked**.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Professional. The project is Azure SDK-based, and the attached process is WaIISHost.exe.

Comment: The machine sending the request is A. The machine hosting the server is B. Your visual studio instance is running on B, right? If so, then you should have w3wp.exe in the process list.

Comment: Yes, thats correct - but the w3wp is not showing, even when doing a request after starting the debugging session using F5.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue was that since I had set up my IIS server to serve on port 83, while locally I would access on port 81, the debugger would not monitor those requests.

To solve this (or, generally, to debug remotely on the Cassini Web Server), download a tool called [rinetd](http://www.boutell.com/rinetd/), which is a very simple traffic redirector daemon, and create a config.cfg in the folder where you extracted it to. The format is `<source ip> <source port> <dest. ip> <dest port>`. So, on my Mac, I go to this address in Safari: 192.168.1.23:8080/Controller/Action , and that is then redirected to localhost:81/Controller/Action , as if it was a local request! Here is the example config.cfg:

```
192.168.1.23 8080 127.0.0.1 81
```

Alternatively, you can use your PC name, to avoid having to assign a static IP or change the config when DHCP gives you a new address:

```
Jeff-PC 8080 127.0.0.1 81
```

Then, open a command prompt, and `cd` to your rinetd folder, and run `rinetd.exe -c config.cfg`.

Works like a charm.

Comment: Awesome!!!!! Thank you so much for posting this! I just gave rinetd a try and it worked perfectly. This opens up so much flexibility for testing apps from (drum roll) my smart phone connected via wifi to a site running out of VS on a dev box on my local network. Now that is cool.

Answer (score 7):

I can see that the remote requests are served by IIS, but the local ones are served via "Cassini" server or the server of visual studio.

Make sure that you are using IIS to debug your code, You can attache visual studio to w3wp.exe to debug via IIS. and you should start visual studio as Administrator.

To attache Visual studio to w3wp.exe (IIS process): From visual studio, from the debug menu select "Attach to process..." :

- Check "Show processes from all users".
- Check "Show processes in all sessions".
- Choose "Managed (v....) code" from (Attach to.) by pressing select button.
- Press "Refresh" button

w3wp.exe should be shown!

[image]

Comment: I don't have the w3wp.exe in my process list - I always run as Admin

Comment: I don't have the "Show processes in all sessions" option anywhere

Comment: I don't have that option - maybe it's cause theres only 1 account on my Windows machine?

Comment: Does it change if I am using Azure Cloud Service, by the way?

Comment: Yes, and (again) I dont have the "Show processes in all sessions" option

Comment: Restart visual studio and run it as administrator.

Comment: The main problem is with "Show processes in all sessions"

Comment: But is w3wp.exe used for Azure SDK projects?

Comment: I figured it out, and I posted my answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you start Visual Studio, start it as Administrator (right click and 'Run as administrator'), then load your project's solution.

Then from the debug menu select "Attach to process..." and ensure that the "Show processes from all users" and "show processes in all sessions" checkboxes are checked, within the Available Processes panel you should be able to scroll through and locate a process that relates to the IIS app pool that you are trying to debug (usually called w3wp.exe).

Attach to this process and refresh the page in your browser, this should allow you to debug.

Many Thanks.

Benjamin

Comment: I don't have the w3wp.exe in my process list :O

Answer (score 2):

You are probably attaching the wrong process.

Try to do the below to confirm you are debugging the wrong process.

- From your local machine start the web application in debug mode (press F5).
- Go on Debug -- > Attach process

Now if you scroll down you should see which is the process VS has attached to debug your application (It should appear in a different color -light gray).  If the process is not the `w3wp.exe` it means you are not using IIS for hosting your application and you are probably debugging the wrong process when you make a request from another machine

Comment: The gray one is WaIISHost.exe

Comment: That means you are not using IIS to debug now!!

Comment: ... but, it says IIS? And I set it in the project properties, and if I am not using IIS, I wouldn't be able to do external requests.

Comment: This means the application is not hosted under IIS.
Are you using Azure SDK on you local machine?
Anyway try to manually attach this process before calling the web application from another machine.

Comment: Yes, Azure SDK! I can't attach to that WaIISHost.exe since it is already attached when I press F5.

Comment: have a look at this link:  http://acloudyplace.com/2012/06/debugging-or-running-an-asp-net-application-without-windows-azure-compute-emulator/
I would raccomend you to install a full version of IIS or IIS express anyway

Comment: I believe I do have the full version - I have the IIS Manager

Comment: have a look at the link I post you on the previous comment

Comment: My app is based heavily on Azure technology, so not using the azure emulators will render my app useless.

Comment: That's the goal of  azure emulators (debugging). 
It's a pain debug azure 
http://www.fullscale180.com/Blog/post/2012/10/07/Remote-Debugging-Windows-Azure-Cloud-Services-with-Visual-Studio-2012.aspx

Comment: I figured it out, and I posted my answer.