# Deploying ASP.NET MVC 5 Application to Win Server 2008

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localhost

I would like to test my ASP.NET MVC application on my tablets and phones on my home local network.

How would I access the website from such devices?

Is it possible to deploy the application to some folder on my Win Server VM and then access the folder by typing that URL in mobile web browsers such as Safari?

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 1):

I will offer up 2 possible solutions here.

1. Learn how to deploy your app to a web server. Here is a microsoft article explaining how to do this at home, in a relatively quick way, and learning skills you may need in the future.
   This is the best way if you need to learn more about deploying. it should get easier each time you do it:
   http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis
2. Leech off your development instance, which *requires* traffic to come in on localhost/127.0.0.1 which will require a traffic-redirector / port-forwarder on your host instance(your developement web server on your host instance has a 'code name', its called Cassini!, its good to know this name when researching about it...) Look at this link, and remember that your IP Address and Port number is most likely not the same as the one in the solution:
   [Debugging ASP.NET MVC3 application hosted on Local IIS Webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623450/debugging-asp-net-mvc3-application-hosted-on-local-iis-webserver/13625361#13625361)

...dont forget about your windows firewall, too...

Comment: My iPV4 address appears as 10.211.55.10. Is this the correct address. Is it worth mentioning that I am running Windows Server in a virtual machine from a Mac computer? Does this somehow affect the address I use?

Comment: Ive now changed to using a bridged wifi setup in my wifi settings and now I have IP: 192.168.0.21. When I type in this address with the 62165 port (asp app) I get Bad Request Invalid Hostname error in Safari

Comment: I get a ping response in mac terminal and have turned the windows firewall off

Comment: will check to see if can still access site with parallels

Comment: website still opens fine in parallels on port 62165. However bad request error persists after reboot

Comment: Found it its: 192.168.0.15

Comment: Not sure where to go from here really

Comment: sorry what do you mean by config? Is that the address to type in? thanks

Comment: I use VMware Fusion. Make sure you have the network adapter settings set to bridged. After settings up the site and application pool in IIS, open your hosts file and add `127.0.0.1    local.yourwebsitename.com` (domain is up to you). Then, on OSX, open your hosts file and point that same domain to the VM's IP address (in this case 192.168.0.15). You should be able to access the local site running on the VM from OS X now. Beware though, my UVERSE router does not allow my VM to use a bridged connection, I had to buy another router to sit in front of it